# How to register application for API implicit authentication?

Tags: support, api

I am working on an applet to for Cairo-Dock, to check the user's StackExchange inbox. Right now I've worked around this by using the genuwine json feed, but that's not stable since posts are marked as read each time the URL is requested.

So the API v. 2.0 provides authentication. In this case--a desktop application--would require implicit authentication. From what I understand, one should first register the application (or the client), to obtain a `client_id` and `redirect_uri`. The documentation is not clear however as to how one registers the application and gets the ID.

Could you advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [click here](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) to register an application. This will provide you with an API key and application ID.

If you want the application to use the implicit OAuth flow, then make sure the "Enable Client Side OAuth Flow" checkbox is checked:

[image]

Comment: PS: shouldn't there be a link to this form the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)?

Comment: Which value should I use in the **OAuth Domain**? From what I understand--since I am making a desktop application--I should use `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`.

Comment: @Benjamin: It can really be anything you want as long as your application recognizes when that domain is redirected to.